# github tag closing in Liquid 4 failure

Tags: github, jekyll, liquid

I am using `Jekyll` and thereby `Liquid 4`

Normally I should be able to escape whitespaces like so:

```
{%- for post in site.data.posts-%}
```

but github returns me following error message on the build
The tag `{%- for post in site.data.posts -%}` on line 21 in `index.html` was not properly closed with `%}`.

if I remove the dashes and format it like so

```
{% for post in site.data.posts %}
```

it is working but with the added white spaces of course everywhere.

I was under the impression it should work with `Liquid 4` and a colleague of mine has the same kind of code and with him this is working.

Any ideas why this is crashing my build?

*from my gemfile*

```
gem "jekyll", "3.5.0"
```

*And from my gemfile.lock*

```
    jekyll (3.5.0)
  addressable (~> 2.4)
  colorator (~> 1.0)
  jekyll-sass-converter (~> 1.0)
  jekyll-watch (~> 1.1)
  kramdown (~> 1.3)
  liquid (~> 4.0)
  mercenary (~> 0.3.3)
  pathutil (~> 0.9)
  rouge (~> 1.7)
  safe_yaml (~> 1.0)
jekyll-feed (0.9.2)
  jekyll (~> 3.3)
jekyll-sass-converter (1.5.0)
  sass (~> 3.4)
jekyll-watch (1.5.0)
  listen (~> 3.0, < 3.1)
kramdown (1.14.0)
liquid (4.0.0)
```

Comment: GIthub still uses Jekyll 3.4.5 + Liquid 3.06 https://pages.github.com/versions/ You'll have to downgrade for the time being.

Comment: Hmm but that is still bizarre that my colleague got it to work in his workstation. Probably something with the added frameworks or something I suppose.

Comment: It should work fine on the workstation, but not on GitHub Pages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your colleague workstation isn't the same as Github platform. You can run your code in a local environment with your current configuration and it will work, because if you run it with `bundle exec jekyll serve` it will get the expected Gemfile dependencies and versions.

But you can't specify custom versions of gems in Github Pages, having a Gemfile won't work. The proper way to replicate Github Pages running environment is to set your `Gemfile` as:

```
gem 'github-pages', group: :jekyll_plugins
```

Then run `bundle install` and check the versions you are using:

```
bundle exec github-pages versions
```

Then you will have to wait until Github Pages uses `Liquid 4.*` to use the whitespace strip feature or write liquid without whitespaces between them, now it is `3.0.6`.

Comment: I do understand, but, my colleague also has this published in github and with him this works perfectly fine. Thus my confusion. [this is his website also available on github as public repo](http://www.schippefilt.com/)

Comment: Current build of your colleague is failing, 12 days ago he made a commit adding the space stripping feature and now the site is failing, showing the previous version.

Comment: You are absolutely correct, thank you for this! Don't know how I missed this to be honest, must have overlooked his build failure as he didn't get an email from github about it.
Any idea how to get rid of the white spaces in another way? or am I stuck with this unless I put everything on one line?

Comment: @Tikkes you can build the site locally with Jekyll 4 and uploaded the generated site to Github pages.